# Как вытащить 2 элемент?

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

Есть код :

```
<div class="price">
<span>Цена:</span>
<span>12 000</span>
</div>
```

Как спарсить только цену?

При

```
$price = $html->find('price');
echo $price->plaintext;
```

показывается 'Цена: 12 000'.

Comment: `$html->find('.price', 0)->find('span', 1)->plaintext`

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает.